# TI MSP430 Launchpad + Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, msp430, launchpad

I just received my TI Launchpad and I'm wondering how can I add something like an Ethernet Shield from Arduino, in order to display a simple webpage... ?
Do you know any Ethernet shield for Launchpad?

Comment: I don't think the msp430G22xx has enough memory or ram to be used as a web server, but I think some of the other msp430 chips can, I thought i saw an application note not too long ago, but could not find it recently

Comment: of course i'm not saying the MSP by it's self, with some PIC or Wiznet controler to do the hard work :D

Comment: I wish you luck, and if you succeed, let me know :)

Answer (score 6):

The Arduino Ethernet shield is built around the Wiznet W5100. The chip provides a complete TCP/IP stack and can ethernet.

Porting the Arduino driver code to the Launchpad should be fairly straightforward, you'll need SPI and a few control lines.

http://code.google.com/p/arduino/source/browse/trunk/libraries/Ethernet/utility/w5100.cpp

Here's some Launchpad SPI code of mine to get you started:

http://blog.hodgepig.org/2010/09/10/575/

The Launchpad currently has no official shield standard though there are efforts afoot:

http://www.43oh.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=16&start=10

http://www.msp430launchpad.com/2010/08/shield-standard-proposal.html